# Dynamically Set height UIView according to UILabel

Tags: swift, uiview, storyboard, uilabel

**i want my answer label increase height according to text and set height of UIView according to answer label height.**

also you tell me your solution. to archiving this goal

here is my storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need you find the height of label first. You can do this by following

```
extension String {
   func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
}
```

And then you can find height like this:

```
let height = "yourString".height(withConstrainedWidth: "THE WIDTH YOU ARE SETTING", UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15))
```

You can keep any width and font that you have set and you will get height.

Now you can keep a height constraint of the view that will be equal to height of label